# Implicit function theorem - how to approach?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry

I have a question that I have been working on for a while. I was wondering how I should approach the following question:

> Are there any points on the graph of the equation 
>   $$x^3+3xy^2+2xy^3=1$$
>   where it may not be possible to solve for $y$ as a smooth function of $x$ in
>   some neighborhood of the point?

Comment: Systems of equations?

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate the Jacobian matrix and determine which points make the column corresponding to the partial derivative of $y$ pivotal/nonpivotal.

EDIT:

The derivative matrix would be $\begin{bmatrix}
3x^2+3y^2, & 6xy+6xy^2
\end{bmatrix}$. What points make $3x^2+3y^2 = 0$ and $6xy+6xy^2\neq 0$? These would be the points where you can solve for $y$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: Well, this function does not seem to have more than one variable. How can I get a 2 x 2 matrix from this function?

Comment: The Jacobian will be $1\times 2$. If the second column is pivotal for some point $(x,y)$, then you should be able to solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ in a neighborhood of that point. Of course, the Jacobian should be surjective.

Comment: When I take the gradient, I get 6xy+6y^2 for the partial derivative with respect to Y...when I solve for Y, I get Y= -6x

Comment: I think you meant $6xy+6y^2$. That would actually be the partial derivative with respect to $y$. The gradient is the transpose of the derivative matrix (the Jacobian).

Comment: still does not help :(

Comment: @JonnyQuiznos: Okay. Where exactly are you getting lost? Do you know how to use the implicit function theorem? Have you tried a similar problem? For instance, you could consider a unit circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and consider where $y$ could be expressed in terms of $x$ and where it could not. I'm happy to help, I just need a little more direction from you (where you getting lost)? Also, if what I am doing does not make sense (you were taught a different way), just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this kind of problem is to use the implicit derivative. Anywhere on the curve where the implicit derivative $dy/dx$ is $\pm \infty$ (on such simple curves), the curve will be momentarily vertical, and at those points $y$ cannot locally be a smooth function of $x$. For your function $f(x,y)=x^3+3xy^2+2xy^3-1$, so curve is $f(x,y)=0$, the implicit derivative is
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{2y^3+3y^2+3x^2}{6xy(y+1)}.$$
So $dy/dx$ will be infinite at points $(x,y)$ of the curve at which the denominator is $0$ and the numerator nonzero. Here the denominator is $0$ at $x=0$, however no points on $f(x,y)=0$ have $x=0$. So there remain the possibilities $y=0,-1$. For $y=0$, substitution in $f(x,y)=0$ gives $x=1$, so that one of the "bad" points is $(1,0).$ And for $y=-1$, substitution in $f(x,y)=0$ gives the equation $x^3+x-1=0$ which has a single solution around $x=0.682328.$ This gives the other "bad" point as $(0.682328,-1)$ approximately. At all other points on the curve, $dy/dx$ is a finite number and so the implicit function theorem says $y$ is locally a smooth function of $x$ near the point.